# Why is QWebEngineView::loadFinished triggered only once?

Tags: qt5, qwebengineview

Here is the code

*CMakeLists.txt*

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(test_QWebEngineView_loading LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS REQUIRED Core Widgets WebEngineWidgets)

set(SOURCE_FILES
  main.cpp
  test.cpp)

add_executable(test_QWebEngineView_loading ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test_QWebEngineView_loading PRIVATE
  Qt5::Core
  Qt5::Widgets
  Qt5::WebEngineWidgets)
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Test w;
    w.resize(800,600);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

*test.h*

```cpp
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>

class Test : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Test(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  ~Test() override;

public slots:

private:
  QWebEngineView *m_website;

  QString m_url;
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

*test.cpp*

```cpp
// Qt headers
#include <QUrl>
#include <QTimer>

// Other headers
#include "test.h"

Test::Test(QWidget* parent /*=nullptr*/):
  QMainWindow(parent)
{;
  m_website = new QWebEngineView();
  setCentralWidget(m_website);
  
  /////////////////////////////////////
  QObject::connect(m_website, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, [this](bool isOk) {
    if (!isOk) {
      qDebug() << "Error when loading URL";
      return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Loading " << m_url << "is finished";

  });
  
  // one loads a first URL
  // Paris
  m_url = QString("https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/48.8578/2.4093");
  qDebug() << "loading " << m_url << "...";
  m_website->load(QUrl(m_url));


  // waiting 2 seconds and then loading a new URL
  QTimer::singleShot(2000, [this](){ // 2 sec.
    // Ha Noi 21.0102/105.8134
    m_url = QString("https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/21.0102/105.8134");
    qDebug() << "loading " << m_url << "...";
    m_website->load(QUrl(m_url));
  });
}

// destructor
Test::~Test()
{
  delete m_website;
}
```

Here is the output:

> loading  "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/48.8578/2.4093" ...

> Loading  "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/48.8578/2.4093" is finished

> loading  "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/21.0102/105.8134" ...

I am wondering why the signal &QWebEngineView::loadFinished is not emitted when I load the second URL while the page is well displayed in the QMainWindow. Why do I not see the line "Loading "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/21.0102/105.8134 is finished"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Qt6.5, I cannot reproduce this behaviour anymore. This issue has probably been fixed in Qt 5.15.5 because a lot of QWebEngineView-related bugs were fixed in this release (see for example [QTBUG-91773](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-91773), [QTBUG-87089](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-87089), [QTBUG-76802](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76802), etc.)